# php jquery voting system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to implement a simple voting system. My page is having list of promos ehere people can give their votes. I am using a voting link like-

```
<button rel="promo_vote" id="promo_vote!<?php echo $promo_contents['promo_index']; ?>" class="more img-circle fa fa-thumbs-up" title="Vote"></button>
```

After clicking it jquery will fill the data in database for that particular promo.And I have taken a button styled properly to use it as the voting counter.I am trying to increase its value dynamically. DB insertion is happening perfectly but counter is not increasing. I guess its not able to recognize the button. Let me show my jquery code.

```
$("[rel=promo_vote").click(function()
{
var p = jQuery(this);
var id_vote_promo = p.attr("id");
var post_id_of_promo = id_vote_promo.substring(id_vote_promo.indexOf('!')+1);
var dataString = 'post_id_of_promo='+ post_id_of_promo;

var id_unvote_promo = "promo_unvote!"+post_id_of_promo;

var vote_counter_id = "#vote_counter!"+post_id_promo;
var value = $(vote_counter_id).val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url to controller",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        value= value+1;
        $(praise_counter_id).val(value);
        $(p).replaceWith("<button rel='promo_unvote'  id='"+id_unvote_promo+"' class='more-alt img-circle fa fa-check' title=''></button>");


    }
});

return false;
});
```

and the counter code is

```
<p class="nm">+ 
  <input type="button" value="1" class="vote_count_btn" id="vote_counter!<?php echo $promo_contents['promo_index']; ?>"  />
  People Voted
</p>
```

Can you help me please where am I missing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/voting-system-with-jquery-php-and-mysql.html

Comment: Where are you using "praise_counter_id" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(vote_counter_id).val(value);
```

in place of

```
$(praise_counter_id).val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am only giving you the way it should be done.  If the promo id is unique, this will work

Step 1:

Give the Paragraphs a unique id based on promo index. Use php to uniquely put the promo_index. In this case I have used a prefix 'nm_'. You will need to add in the dynamic promo index via php.

```
<p class="nm" id="nm_<--promo_index_id-->">+ 
  <input type="button" value="1" class="vote_count_btn" id="vote_counter!<?php echo $promo_contents['promo_index']; ?>"  />
  People Voted
</p>
```

Step 2:

Use afix nm with promo index:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url to controller",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(res){
        value= value+1;
        $(praise_counter_id).val(value);
        $("nm_"+praise_counter_id).replaceWith("<button rel='promo_unvote'  id='"+id_unvote_promo+"' class='more-alt img-circle fa fa-check' title=''></button>");


    }
});
```